# can copy large file to nas

Tags: raid, data-recovery, nas

I'm trying to recover a faulty raid and I have successfully recovered it , I'm using a software called UFS explorer to rebuild the raid 5 and I can see the files 
when I try to save the recovered files to my nas ( Qnap TS-569 pro, 4 X 3TB hard drives raid 0 to give me 10TB of space )
it copies the folder structure and small files (1KB) but comes with the error saying : when trying to copy my large file and ther is only 6 files on the raid :

Files saving log. Produced by UFS Explorer software

```
Processed objects:
File: Server2012storage-flat.vmdk

To: //192.168.1.129/recovered/Server2012storage-flat.vmdk

Errors log follows:
Failed to process //192.168.1.129/recovered/Server2012storage-flat.vmdk: Unable to open source file
```

the file is 4.8TB yes tera byte

I just cant find the reason why is that so 
nas is connected with giga bit cable to switch 
I'm connected to computer remotely 
will it make any deference if I use other ports like usb or esata ?
or am I missing a configuration here I have no data on the nad so I can rebuild the data space please give me suggestions 
I don't even know if its a problem finding the nas or with the raid I'm trying to recover from .

Comment: The recovered fie is probably corrupted, so it can't copy it.

Comment: What filesystem? Protocol? Server type/version?

Comment: protocol is TCP/IP

Comment: protocol is TCP/IP,hard drives has been in a buffalo nas , I'm not too sure about the system file , I didn't set it up I belonged to a company , I'm trying to recover data for them

Comment: Does your computer have a gigabit ethernet adapter, @JacobSinger? I'd recommend you to try upgrading that and see if the transfer rate will get back to normal for your massive files. Another thing that could be affecting the transfer is an antivirus or a firewall software. You could also try disabling your antivirus software or even switch to a different one and see if that would makes things better. Hope this helps. Keep us posted. :)